# Is this grammar correct?

Tags: grammar

[image: Description about Obama]

It was a screenshot from a video on Youtube. I interested with the description saying "..., he was the first African American **to be** elected to the presidency......"

I bold the **to be** as in my understanding, the sentence should be "..., he was the first African American elected to the presidency......"

My question is: is the original sentence's grammar correct? If it is not, how about my sentence?

Comment: Both versions are correct. I don’t think there is even a difference in nuance between them.

Comment: As many times I saw on tv, if a story of a movie will be continued, there will be written "*to be** continued", mean that the story "**will be** continued." Then **to be** is a future event in passive sentence. I am wrong with that my understanding?

Comment: _to be_ is just the infinitive form of the verb _be_. It doesn't have a tense, future or past, by definition.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U, but please do not post screenshots of text. They are very unfriendly to people using screen readers, they do not resize predictably on different devices, and they prevent the question from being indexed by search engines, both internally and on the Internet. Besides, if you cannot be bothered to copy and paste or transcribe a few sentences, it is a little presumptuous to ask that others write you a full answer.

Comment: How can you ask about whether the grammar is correct and write your questions ungrammatically?

Comment: @choster, apologize if you feel something inappropriate with the screen shot. I have to attach it as I have to show where I get the sentence. As in my experience in anther part of this SE, If I didn't include the case, then will be many question such "where did you get the idea?". Second, I did it from mobile, so there is no way to adjust the size. I appreciate if someone can tell me how to adjust the size.

Comment: @AirCraftLover As I noted, all you need to do is *transcribe* the text. You do not need to post the screenshot to show your source—it would have been better to post a link to the YouTube video itself.

Comment: For sure, I will. It was just my misunderstanding comparing between here and another part of this SE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We often reduce adjective clauses or join separate sentences for the sake of precision or for  close knitting of construction. For same purpose often past participle phrases are used  when the person or the thing is acted upon

He was the first African American (to be) elected to the Presidency. =

- He was the first African American.
- He was elected to the Presidency.

We have two alternatives; either to make the second sentence an infinitival phrase where "To be" is a state of being or a past participal phrase where by removing HE WAS the rest of the sentence becomes qualifying. Nevertheless, two phrases  qualify " African American ". No future meaning is conveyed by " to be ". Both of them are correct and the subtle nuances they bear are from the point of construction, but little of functional.

Comment: 1). *Both of them are correct....* what are them you said *both*? 2). If the formal written English test (such as TOEFL), is the original sentence correct?

Comment: To be elected .../ elected... Both. The difference being that the original version there is something of a distinction between an 'African American' and ' to be elected...' While in the latter two states mix and mingle. Yes, the original sentence is correct.